# D-link managed switch or Cisco managed switch?

Tags: vlan, security

Can anyone tell me the difference between D-link managed switch and cisco managed switch? And why we go for cisco managed switch.

Comment: Which switch models?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There may be several differences which may be important to you - or not. As with any purchase, you should know what your requirements are, what you'd like in addition to that, and what you're willing to spend.

- Features - what features do you require and what level in each feature?
- Compatibility - make it easier to coexist with devices and tools already in your network
- Familiarity - if you're already familiar with a device series you save on training
- Performance - is a device up to your application requirements and can you scale up from there? networks tend to grow
- Documentation - advanced features require a decent level of documentation to be useful
- Support - does the vendor offer your required level of support?